# Ruby on Rails add path in link_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this:

```
      <li><%= link_to "More", feed_products_path(product.id) ,{:class=>"button-small white"} %></li>
```

This link outputs:
    http://localhost:3000/feed_products.34

I would like to see if as:
    http://localhost:3000/feed_products/34

How do I do this in Ruby on Rails?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your routes file too.

Comment: I just did   resources :feed_products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the path in above link to with

```
 feed_product_path(product)
```

feed_products_path is for the index action. If you pass an object to it then it appears as format("format" => "1"), 1 being the id of the object passed, in the params hash.

I hope you are not trying to pass an object there. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: may be  feed_product_path(@product) depending on controller.

Comment: yea, may be :) but the OP is successfully accessing it as a local and not an instance variable.

Comment: Yeah this works. Thanks. I do have some follow up questions:

Why did you say this? "I hope you are not trying to pass an object there. Let me know if this helps."

and whats the difference between passing product and @product

Ruby / Ruby on Rails Newbie.

Comment: feed_products_path is routed to index action of FeedProducts controller. Generally, all corresponding objects are accessed in an index action. So, it does not make sense passing a specific object(of the same class) to an index action. Lets consider a show action feed_product_path(product), which requires an object to be passed, i.e. specify which specific object is to be shown.

Comment: '@product' is an instance variable. If you define it in an action, you can access it in the corresponding view(and otherwise for a local variable). Say '@products' in index action and '@products.each do |product|' in your view. S0, '@products' in the instance variable and in your view 'product' is a local variable. Its scope is only in that view, i.e. you need to pass it to a partial or a helper.
Finally, (woosh) with "Let me know if this helps", I was just trying to be polite and helpful :)